# When I tried to save a Email Template in Admin, it thows me a 404 error: Page not found (only with some values and only in production)

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, email-templates, 404-page

Recently we upload our site to **Production Server**. In **Developer Server** all is apparently Ok. But, in production server, in **Admin**, when I go to ***Marketing >  Email Templates***, and I try to modify some Template or Add a New one, some times the page throw me to a white page with only the black words: **"404 error: Page not found."**

After some tests, I saw that it only occurs when the Template Content field has in his text instructions like **{{var ...}}** or **{{trans ...}}** When the text is Plain HTML, it is saved without problem. At same time, instructions like **{{depend ...}}** or **{{if ...}}** Neither do they cause problems. For now, it is only when the text have {{var ...}} or {{trans ...}}. For example:

```
{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}

{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}
```

As I said, it only occurs in my production server, in developer server works fine. I tried to upload again all my vendor directory, but the result was the same.

I do some more tests, and the strange thing is, when the error occurs, it doesn´t enter to the method **execute()** in **vendor\magento\module-email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\Save.php**, it goes directly to the 404 page. But, why only occurs when the text have that instructions? I don´t understand.

Someone have any idea?

My **Magento versio**n is **2.1.1**

Comment: What is the actual URL that you are on when you see the 404?

Comment: Hi nikola99, the url is like this: **https://[Site's Domain]/admin/admin/email_template/save/id/2/key/4fdd379be11598a115bd571b35b4fd1184b05c0f9e84d7b266bdc99e161e6430/**